# is there any way to truncate table in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

I know that in some relational database like MySQL, you can truncate table by using

```
truncate table table_name
```

Does TDengine support truncate table, or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

truncate is not supported in TDengine database, but truncate data from a table can be done by following command:

```
delete from table_name
```

BTW, delete command is only supported by enterprise version